# SOAP API access to SFMC doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I am following the README on FUEL SDK and trying to get access to SFMC via SOAP API.

```
    auth = SalesforceTokenProvider()
    access_token = auth.get_token()

    myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(
        params={
          'clientid': Config.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID,
          'clientsecret': Config.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET,
          'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
          'defaultwsdl': 'https://SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/etframework.wsdl',
          'authenticationurl': 'https://SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token',
          'baseapiurl': "https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/",
          'soapendpoint': "https://SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx",
          'wsdl_file_local_loc': r'ExactTargetWSDL.xml',
          'useOAuth2Authentication': True,
          'authorizationCode': access_token
         })
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: {'error': 'unsupported_grant_type', 'error_description': 'Use "authorization_code" or "refresh_token" or "client_credentials" or "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" as the grant_type.', 'error_uri': 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs'}
```

I was looking at the source code client.py and it has this:

```
            legacyString = "?legacy=1"
            if legacyString not in self.auth_url:
                self.auth_url = self.auth_url.strip()
                self.auth_url = self.auth_url + legacyString

            r = requests.post(self.auth_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
            tokenResponse = r.json()
            
            if 'accessToken' not in tokenResponse:
                raise Exception('Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: ' + repr(r.json()))
```

it adds this string to the authenticator url which I dont understand. Is this the problem? Shouldnt the url end with /v2/token?

Answer (score 0):

True should have been a string and not a bool